# use mysqldump to create file which can be restored using single query

Tags: mysql

i´m wondering if it is possible to create a mysql backup using mysqldump so that i am able to push the result to a single query for restore the database.

Background:

I would like to use a console based c program which loads the dump file and push it via query to the database.

Thanks for your hints and

Kind regards

Solick

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "a single query"?

The usual way to load a dump is

```
shell> mysql -u user -p database < your_dump_file
```

But you can also do

```
mysql> source 'path/your_dump_file';
```

You have to do nothing special with `mysqldump`.

Except maybe, you use the `--tab` parameter with `mysqldump`. Then a comma separated values (.csv)  file is created. You can import it with `LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE...` command. But this only works for single tables, not whole databases.

Comment: As i wrote i want to use the dump within an c program, which means using the libmysqlclient api. There i want to load the dump file and execute it within a call of mysql_real_query();

Comment: ...and the `source 'your_dump_file';` should be executable with mysql_real_query() in my eyes. Anyway, if it doesn't help you, it might help others. I'll leave it like that.